# getting undefined value for uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL in firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

This is my first time using firebase in a web app.

In my code I'm trying to add a node, The child node thumbnail is **undefined** and is not getting added in the firebase database.

Kindly provide a solution as I have tried re writing same code in different ways but

```
uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
```

always returns undefined

Thanks in advance for the help.
PFB the JS code and firebase console screenshot.

```
var database = firebase.database().ref("categories/"+catname);
    database.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
            $("#result").html("Category already exist");
        }else{
            var name = thumbnail["name"];
            var ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."),name.length);

            var thumbname = new Date().getTime();
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(catname+"/"+thumbname+ext);
            const ref = firebase.storage().ref(catname+"/"+thumbname+ext);


            var uploadTask = storageRef.put(thumbnail);
            uploadTask.on("state_changed",
                function progress(snapshot){
                    var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
                    $("#upload-progress").html(percentage+"%");
                    $("#upload-progress").attr("style","width:"+percentage+"%");
                },
                function error(err){

                },
                function complete(snapshot){
                    var thumbURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                    console.log(thumbURL);
                    console.log(uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL);
                    var cat = {
                        "thumbnail":thumbURL||null,
                        "desc":desc||null
                    };
                    database.set(cat,function(err){
                        if(err){
                            $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-danger");
                            $("#result").html(err.message);
                        } else {
                            $("#result").attr("class","alert alert-success");
                            $("#result").html("Category created successfully");
                        }
                    });
                }
                
            );

        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `downloadURL` property of UploadTaskSnapshot is [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot#downloadurl)
The [firebase examples](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/12f71f2a94a46bbfe2c1ebac33189ddfc53a764e/storage/upload-files.js#L163-L210) are suggesting to use  `ref` as in

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
});
```